# Can I use a UPS to compensate for unsteady line-power?

Tags: mains, ups

One of the outlets in my home provides unsteady power that causes connected electronics to occasionally shut down. If I buy a battery backup device such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019804U8) will it be able to compensate for frequent power dips without eventually loosing its charge? And will the frequent power dips quickly wear it out?

Comment: Yes, it will work. If you have constant/very frequent brownouts you need a line-interactive or an online UPS. That was the bad power will not drain the batteries.

Answer (score 2):

> One of the outlets in my home provides unsteady power that causes
>   connected electronics to occasionally shut down

If one of the outlets in your home provides unsteady power then it needs looking into - it's probably a loose wire in the socket or a faulty wire somewhere in the distribution of power to that socket. Don't waste your money on a UPS - get the problem fixed.

Comment: It might be more expensive and time consuming to hire an electrician to fix the wiring than to buy a UPS. So I'd still like to know if using a UPS will work and if there are any risks involved.

Comment: It is eventually cheaper to hire an electrician than to 'hire' the fire department.

Comment: @Nathan Without an in depth study of the type of problem you are having, it's guesswork - how can anybody say if a UPS will work on the power outlet that causes connected electronics to shut-down.